# insert cursor "Row contains a bad value"

Tags: arcpy, cursor

I'm having a problem copying data from a shapefile to a feature class using an insert cursor.  Here is the part that is causing trouble:

```
newRows = arcpy.InsertCursor(Target)
sourceRows = arcpy.SearchCursor(Christiansburg)

for source in sourceRows:
    neue = newRows.newRow()
    neue.setValue(TName, source.getValue(CName))
    newRows.insertRow(neue)
```

It takes data from a field in the source row, and then copies it to the new row.  The trouble is, when the source row has a forward slash in it, it fails when I try to do the insert, saying "The row contains a bad value.". If I edit the forward slash out of the source data, it works fine. If I replace the variable with a hardwired string that has a forward slash in it, it also works fine, so I am not 100% sure that it is the forward slash causing the problem.  I have tried using the str function on the result of getValue, and it still doesn't work. The field being copied from is street names, and the row causing trouble is a street that changes name.  If worst comes to worst, I could simply edit out the forward slash permanently, but I would rather not if I can help it.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here?

EDIT: Derped on copy/paste of code snippet. Should be fixed now.

Comment: Do you have nulls? What version of ArcGIS are you on?

Comment: There are nulls in other fields, however, there are none in field that is causing trouble, either in the feature class or shapefile. Have 10.0

Comment: ahmm shouldnt you use: newRows.insertRow(neue) after you are finished iterating sourceRows? setValue() is filling just one field in a row or multiple fields simultaneously?

Comment: As I understand it, it needs to be done for each row. setValue fills a single field in a single row. So you create a row object, fill it with setValue as needed, insert the row into the table, and move on to next source row, hence the loop. I am actually using other setValue statements for other fields in my full code, but only what I have posted is causing problems.  Even that is not consistently problematic, since it only seems to cause problems when the source row has a '/' in it, and I can't figure out how to fix it.

Comment: Maybe arcpy think the street name is a filepath. Why don't you try to add a backslash (\) in the value so it sees it as a 'raw' string e.g. from 'old name/new name' to old name\/new name'. Worths a try...

Comment: The last line of the code is `newRows.insertRow(neue)`, but `neue` is setup to create a new row... Could that be the issue?

Comment: @Roy:  As I understand it, neue should be a row object, just sitting in space, then I do stuff with it, and enter it into the feature class using insertRow.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I figured out what the problem was. Turns out, the field in the target feature class has a field length of 35 characters, while the corresponding field in the shapefile has a field length of 256 characters.  The row that was causing problems was exactly 36 characters long, and was the only one that had a '/'.  So when I deleted the '/' that brought the length to 35 characters and it worked. I suspect I spelled something wrong when I hardwired the string, so that is probably why that worked then. I truncated the row to 35 and it works like a charm, even with the '/'.  So that must have been the problem. Thanks to all who took the time to reply and think about it, especially mapoholic.  I noticed this testing his suggestion.  I guess the moral of the story is to make sure that your fields are the right length when doing this sort of thing.

Comment: I had a similar issue, but for me it had to do with a mismatch of number type fields - I was trying to calculate a long integer into a short integer field and the number was too large for the short integer field.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue with Append Tool. I started an Edit Session and the errors went away! weird!

Comment: This comment solved the problem for me. I have been pulling my hair out over this for the last 3 days.